# ConTeXt: Preformatted text inside tables

Tags: context

I want to insert preformatted text into a table. I tried to accomplish this with `\startlines` but the command shows no effect in tables. It is possible with `\break` but this is no real solution.

How can I insert preformatted text inside tables?

MWE:

```
\starttext

\startlines
multi
lines
work
\stoplines

\bTABLE
  \bTR
    \bTD
    \startlines
multi
lines
work
    \stoplines
    \eTD
    \bTD
multi\break
lines\break
work
    \eTD
  \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with `natural tables` is that each cell saves the content before the `lines` environment can see the text as individual lines.

You can work around this when you put the the text for the `lines` environment in a `buffer`. When you load now the content of the buffer in the table the text stays in separate lines.

```
\starttext

\startbuffer[lines]
multi
lines
work
\stopbuffer

\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD
            \startlines
            \getbuffer[lines]
            \stoplines
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

When you have only a few lines of text you can skip the `lines` environment and use the `\\` command to mark the end of each text line in the table cells.

```
\starttext

\bTABLE
    \bTR
        \bTD
            multi\\
            lines\\
            work
        \eTD
    \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

Another possibility is to replace `natural tables` with the `xtable` environment which can handle `lines` without problems because it uses a different method to calculate the table dimensions.

```
\starttext

\startxtable
    \startxrow
        \startxcell
            \startlines
            multi
            lines
            work
            \stoplines
        \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptext
```